# Recursive additive function from one cell value to an existing cell value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, cumulative-sum

I am using google sheets. I have a worksheet like this:

(sorry, I don't know how to link a picture here. And the table I made with just text became all jagged)

When user changes A1's value from 100 to 150, I want B1's value change from 200 to 350. The next time user changes A1's value from 150 to 200, I want B1's value change from 350 to 550... and so on.

Sadly, I am new to programming. So, I am learning how to use scripts in Google Sheets.

[image: Question]

Comment: Can you please share a copy of your spreadsheet (after removing / anonymising confidential information, if any)? In the spreadsheet or in your question above, please describe the range that can change, the range that needs to be updated, an any other constraint that may need to be respected when solving this, as it is currently a bit too broad. E.g. if you change the value in B1, do you need to update A1 too, or only A3:3? Or nothing, only A1 has to impact the rest of them cells?

Comment: share a link to your sheet by pasting it here

Comment: So what you want is for when a user changes a value in A1 to add that value of the cell at B1?

Comment: Yes, AMolina3... that's it. But, B1 should keep track of the old value so that the new value = Old value + New value of A1

Comment: See my question... I have added a picture of the requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution, making the hypothesis that all values in the first line trigger the update for the rest of them.

EDITED: adjusted to only consider changes in A1 and always add the new value of A1 to the other cells in first row ; also forced the script to interpret numbers as such to avoid some undesired concatenations.

```
function onEdit(e){
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() == "A1") { 
    var difference = isNaN(e.value) ? 0 : Number(e.value); // New value of A1 to be added to the other cells in first row ; only taking numbers into account
    var firstRowValues = e.range.getSheet().getRange("1:1").getValues(); // Get the current values of the first row
    for (var c = 1 ; c < e.range.getSheet().getLastColumn() ; c++){
      // Go through each value in first row
      // If it has a value already, and if that value is a number, add the difference
      if (firstRowValues[0][c] && !isNaN(firstRowValues[0][c])) firstRowValues[0][c] = Number(firstRowValues[0][c]) + difference;
    }
    e.range.getSheet().getRange("1:1").setValues(firstRowValues); // Set the updated value in the sheet's first row

  }
}
```

EDITED: after addition of the screenshots in the original question, I understand only B1 ever needs to be updated, so the code can be simplified like this:

```
function onEdit(e){
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() == "A1") { 
    var difference = isNaN(e.value) ? 0 : Number(e.value); // New value of A1 to be added to the other cells in first row ; only taking numbers into account
    var valueB1 = e.range.getSheet().getRange("B1").getValue(); // Get the current values of B1
    if (valueB1 && !isNaN(valueB1)) valueB1 = Number(valueB1) + difference; // Only updating if B1 has a value which is a number
    e.range.getSheet().getRange("B1").setValue(valueB1); // Set the updated value in B1  
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Benoit. There is no range. It is just A1 cell that always gets updated/changed by the user. And therefore, B1 will change accordingly but B1 should keep track of the previous value to add the new A1 value to be added to it.

Comment: Thank you. So, how do I add it to Google Sheets?

Comment: Tools > Script editor --> paste there, save, and that should be it

Comment: OK, I'll give it a whirl and report in a few hours. Thank you!

Comment: Sadly, I am unable to share the error I got when I added this code in the script editor. How does one go about adding a screen grab in a comment?

Comment: This is the error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined (line 2, file "Code")Dismiss

Comment: When did this error pop up? When changing the value of A1? Or did you try to execute it manually? The latter won't work as indeed, there won't be an event passed in the function's arguments.

Comment: Your edited code works like a charm. Thank you so much for this!

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A1:A), SUMIF(ROW(A1:A), "<="&ROW(A1:A), A1:A)+A1, ))
```

[image]

Comment: Player0, Thanks for your reply - But, the user always changes A1 values only. And based on the new A1 value, B1 should get updated.

Comment: See my question... I have added a picture of the requirement